# Gitlab-ci .yaml configuration for posting Postman tests via Jira Xray API

Tags: yaml, postman, gitlab-ci, cicd, jira-xray

**My .gitlab-ci.yaml file v**

```
stages:
    - test

postman_tests:
    stage: test
    image: 
        name: postman/newman_alpine33
        entrypoint: [""]
    script:
        - newman --version
        - npm install -g newman-reporter-junitfull
        - npm install -g newman-reporter-junitxray
        - apk add --update curl && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
        - newman run https://api.postman.com/collections/25618800-2d1d5da6-05f3-4d88-88d1-faebffca89f7?access_key=PMAT-01GTVPN0MGG60TY1EX9G4JTFEH -r 'cli,junitfull,junitxray' --reporter-junitfull-export postman_echo_junitfull.xml
        - export token=$(curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data "{ \"client_id\": \"$client_id\",\"client_secret\": \"$client_secret\" }"  https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/api/v2/authenticate| tr -d '"')
        - echo $token
        - 'curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $token"  --data @"postman_echo_junitfull.xml" https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/api/v2/import/execution/junit?projectKey=TSTXR&testPlanKey=${TESTPLAN}'
    artifacts:
        when: always
        paths:
            - postman_echo_junitfull.xml
```

**For line below I get an error (red underline) about "Nested mappings are not allowed in compact mappingsYAML(0)" and "Incorrect type. Expected "string | array".yaml-schema: [https://gitlab.com/assets/webpack/ci.030957f4.json"](https://gitlab.com/assets/webpack/ci.030957f4.json%22)**

`export token=$(curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data "{ \"client_id\": \"$client_id\",\"client_secret\": \"$client_secret\" }"  https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/api/v2/authenticate| tr -d '"')`

**Could someone please help and correct it for me as I don't know where the issue is**

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The YAML syntax is giving you trouble here. Because your string contains a literal colon character (`:`) you're accidentally creating a key-value (`key: value`) mapping in YAML. To avoid this, you should use quotes around your script item to explicitly make sure it is interpreted as a string. You'll also need to escape the inner quotes.

For example, wrap the line in single quotes (`'`) and then the literal single quotes within your string need to be escaped by prefixing them with another single quote -- `''` within a single-quoted string is interpreted to be a single literal quote (`'`). Like this:

```yaml
script:
  # ...
  - 'export token=$(curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data "{ \"client_id\": \"$client_id\",\"client_secret\": \"$client_secret\" }"  https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/api/v2/authenticate| tr -d ''"'')'
  # ...
```